# laravel asset-pipeline doesn"t load jquery

Tags: php, laravel, asset-pipeline

I'have instaled codesleeve/asset-pipeline and use command **php artisan assets:update**

got **no errors**, but when I load the page an in my chrome developer tools go to **Network** tab there is **jQuery-1.10.2.min.map 404 not found**

could please someone tell me if I forgot to do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, a minimized source file will be unreadable since all the whitespace & comments are removed. The `.min.map` file allows the client to "rebuild" the original source for the purposes of browsing & debugging. Thus, if you want/need to debug jQuery, you might want to get that file.

If that file is missing, your application should still work properly. So, the short answer to your question is "no, you didn't forget anything". You can safely ignore that warning.